# ERROR during Wordpress Installation "There has been a critical error on this website."

Tags: plugins, errors, debug

I am installing the wordpress 5.8.6 version...but during the installtion I got this error..
I'm trying to resolve it by renaming the plugin folder name and by also debuging mode in true mode...but all in vain.
I am Beginner into it please guide me!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Have a look in your web server's error log, or your PHP error log if different, or WordPress's own debug.log if you've enabled that in wp-config.php. There should be a specific error and a stack trace. Please edit them into the question if you find them.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to install an old version?